# Email Validation Bound value in a conditional binding must be of Optional type

Tags: macos, validation, email, swift

I have the code below to check if a string is a valid email. After updating to Swift 1.2 , I'm now seeing the error:

```
Bound value in a conditional binding must be of Optional type
```

On the line

```
if let emailTest = NSPredicate(format:"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegEx)
```

I'm not sure what I should do to remove this error. Any suggestions?

Thanks

```
 func isValidEmail(testStr:String) -> Bool {
        println("validate calendar: \(testStr)")
        let emailRegEx = "[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}"

        if let emailTest = NSPredicate(format:"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegEx) {
            return emailTest.evaluateWithObject(testStr)
        }
        return false
    }

    println("Email is: \(isValidEmail(email))")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your function to this :

```
func isValidEmail(testStr : String) -> Bool {
    println("validate calendar: \(testStr)")
    let emailRegEx = "[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}"       

    let emailTest = NSPredicate(format:"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegEx)

    if emailTest.evaluateWithObject(testStr) {
        return true
    }
    return false
}
```

Or you can change it to this too :

```
var emailTest = NSPredicate(format:"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegEx)        
var result = emailTest.evaluateWithObject(testStr)        
return result
```

And should be work too. I hope this help you.

Comment: Original questioner’s `let` was better practice than `var`.

Comment: @AirspeedVelocity Yes, you're right, answer formatted

Answer (score 0):

Good news! `NSPredicate(format:)` doesn’t appear to be a failable initializer, so there’s no need to test and unwrap it – it’s guaranteed to work.  So you can just write:

```
func isValidEmail(testStr:String) -> Bool {
    println("validate calendar: \(testStr)")
    let emailRegEx = "[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}"
    let emailTest = NSPredicate(format:"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegEx)
    return emailTest.evaluateWithObject(testStr)
}
```

(I don’t have 6.2 installed but presumably it was briefly failable between such things being introduced and them re-auditing it and marking it infallible)